# Why i can't obtain driving network of the United States with the package OSMNX in python?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

Iam using the function osmnx.graph_from_place of package osmnx in Python. I want to get the driving network of the entire United States. Here is a part of my code:

```
import osmnx as ox
EU1=ox.graph_from_place('United States', network_type='drive')
```

Here is the error message i got: **'ValueError: No Shapely geometry can be created from null value'**.

So i tried this:

```
EU1=ox.graph_from_place('United States', network_type='drive', which_result=2)
```

I have got another error message : **'TypeError: Geometry must be a shapely Polygon or MultiPolygon. If you requested graph from place name, make sure your query resolves to a Polygon or MultiPolygon, and not some other geometry, like a Point. See OSMnx documentation for details.'**

Someone could please tell me what's wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that `'United States'` is how you're supposed to specify the country?  All of the examples I'm seeing online use `USA` (although they're all in the context of specifying a city or state within the USA, rather than attempting to retrieve the entire country).

Comment: @jasonharper i have tried USA, but it gives me another geographical area, not the united states.

Comment: @gboieng please, can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Do smaller regions work? E.g. "New York"?

Comment: @scai yes, it works with smaller regions

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with osmnx. Maybe osmnx can't handle polygons consisting of multiple closed ways (the US consists of several separated geographical areas). Alternatively try to use the `geocode_to_gdf` function that is mentioned in the `graph_from_place` documentation.

Comment: the function geocode_to_gdf help to download place shapes from OpenStreetMap (as geopandas GeoDataFrames) and not street networks

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the driving network of the entire United States.

The big issues here are 1) you would need hundreds of GB of RAM to construct its model in memory and 2) it would take an exceptionally long time to download all of its pieces across thousands of Overpass queries. For point 1, there are already other answers on this site explaining how to filter your query for just major freeways, for instance, to use less memory. For point 2, you may want to acquire the source data as a .osm file and load that instead. Short answer: you need enough RAM and a faster way to download the data.

EDIT: the other problem is (likely) that you're geocoding to the geometry (the entire US, including Alaska and Hawaii) that spans the antimeridian, making a mess of the buffering and projection necessary to download the graph data. You can see it, like this:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(log_console=True)
gdf = ox.geocode_to_gdf('United States')
gdf.plot()
```

Comment: thanks @gboieng for your answer. I understand that i need enough RAM and a faster way to download the data. Let's suppose i solve theses  issues , now  what about the error messages i got. Do you know why iam having these error messages?